How to uninstall a package from Debian backports (not a duplicate Q)
I know there are a few Questions here which ask the same question I appear to be asking. I have tried those suggestions 1 & 2, but they do not work in this case. Here's what has happened:
pi@raspberrypi0w:~ $ sudo apt -t bullseye-backports install udev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libudev1
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libudev1 udev
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 35 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,654 kB of archives.
After this operation, 511 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports/main armhf udev armhf 252.5-2~bpo11+1 [1,554 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports/main armhf libudev1 armhf 252.5-2~bpo11+1 [100 kB]
Fetched 1,654 kB in 1s (1,267 kB/s)
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 43648 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../udev_252.5-2~bpo11+1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking udev (252.5-2~bpo11+1) over (247.3-7+rpi1+deb11u2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libudev1_252.5-2~bpo11+1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libudev1:armhf (252.5-2~bpo11+1) over (247.3-7+rpi1+deb11u2) ...
Setting up libudev1:armhf (252.5-2~bpo11+1) ...
Setting up udev (252.5-2~bpo11+1) ...
Segmentation fault
Job for systemd-udevd.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
See "systemctl status systemd-udevd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript udev, action "restart" failed.
● systemd-udevd.service - Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service; static)
     Active: activating (start) since Tue 2024-04-09 07:36:27 UTC; 130ms ago
TriggeredBy: ● systemd-udevd-control.socket
             ● systemd-udevd-kernel.socket
       Docs: man:systemd-udevd.service(8)
             man:udev(7)
   Main PID: 8773 ((md-udevd))
      Tasks: 1
        CPU: 45ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-udevd.service
             └─8773 (md-udevd)

Apr 09 07:36:28 raspberrypi0w systemd[1]: Stopped Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files.
Apr 09 07:36:28 raspberrypi0w systemd[1]: Starting Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files...
Apr 09 07:36:28 raspberrypi0w systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Apr 09 07:36:28 raspberrypi0w systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Apr 09 07:36:28 raspberrypi0w systemd[1]: Failed to start Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files.
Apr 09 07:36:28 raspberrypi0w systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Apr 09 07:36:28 raspberrypi0w systemd[1]: Stopped Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files.
Apr 09 07:36:28 raspberrypi0w systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 09 07:36:28 raspberrypi0w systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Apr 09 07:36:28 raspberrypi0w systemd[1]: Failed to start Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files.
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 installed udev package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u8) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

The attempted "reversion" wasn't very interesting:
pi@raspberrypi0w:~ $ apt install ${udev}/bullseye
Illegal instruction

I attempted a few other "reversions":
pi@raspberrypi0w:~ $ sudo apt install udev
Illegal instruction
pi@raspberrypi0w:~ $ sudo apt-get install udev/stable
Illegal instruction
pi@raspberrypi0w:~ $ sudo apt-get install udev/old-stable
Illegal instruction

A 'segmentation fault' - sounds serious :). I was unsure what this meant; i.e. did the system automatically reject the udev upgrade & revert automatically? - or have I stepped in it? I waited a few minutes & tried this:
$ systemctl status systemd-udevd.service
● systemd-udevd.service - Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Tue 2024-04-09 07:36:28 UTC; 28min ago
TriggeredBy: ● systemd-udevd-control.socket
             ● systemd-udevd-kernel.socket
       Docs: man:systemd-udevd.service(8)
             man:udev(7)
    Process: 8776 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd (code=killed, signal=SEGV)
   Main PID: 8776 (code=killed, signal=SEGV)
        CPU: 199ms

Apr 09 07:36:28 raspberrypi0w systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Apr 09 07:36:28 raspberrypi0w systemd[1]: Stopped Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files.
Apr 09 07:36:28 raspberrypi0w systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 09 07:36:28 raspberrypi0w systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Apr 09 07:36:28 raspberrypi0w systemd[1]: Failed to start Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files.

I have a good (image) backup from last night, so if I've killed my OS I can recover. However, I'd prefer to fix this without resort to the backup - if that's possible.
What should I do?

On a setup where udev is able to run, the other posts you found do give the correct recipe to revert a package upgrade to backports:
sudo apt install udev/bullseye

or possibly
sudo apt install udev/oldstable

(with whichever code name or synonym is appropriate). There is a caveat here which is that Debian doesn’t support package downgrades; they work fine most of the time, but if they don’t, it’s not a bug.
You can’t do that because udev won’t run. You’ve ended up in that situation because the Debian armhf architecture targets ARMv7, whereas the initial generation of Raspberry Pis (including the Zero W) implement ARMv6; the appropriate Debian architecture on these systems is armel. As a general rule, you can’t mix and match Debian backports with another distribution, even if it is a Debian derivative. That’s even more the case on Raspbian since the architecture definitions are different.
To fix this without reinstalling, you’d have to download the appropriate udev package, and manually extract its binaries; they would then be usable, which would allow the package to be properly reverted.
Given that you’re keen on using backported packages, you might be better off re-installing with a Debian image for Raspberry Pi. (That would give you newer packages than you’d get with Debian 11 and backports, so you might not even need backports!)
